# Swift explicit variable declaration with optional

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift and trying to decode one of the Apple examples. Could someone please explain what this line is doing ?

```
@SceneStorage("selection") private var selectedProjectID: Project.ID?
```

Project is a struct conforming to `Codable` and `Identifiable`

Is selectedProjectID of the same type as Project.ID? ?

Comment: That means `selectedProjectID` is able to be set to `nil`. So you could do `selectedProjectID = nil`.

Comment: Thanks, I understood that bit - sorry, should have been clearer. Does the Project.Id bit mean selectedProjectID will be of explicit type the same as the Project.ID member in the struct ?

Comment: `Project.ID` probably refers to a nested struct - so the `ID` struct is nested inside the `Project` struct somewhere. Nested doesn't really mean anything, just that you won't be able to reference `ID` by itself - you need to use `Project.ID`.

Comment: No, you've misunderstood. `Project.ID` is not some `id` _property_ of Project. It is another _type_, declared _inside_ Project. See the docs on nested types. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/NestedTypes.html

Comment: Thank you, I misunderstood that ID was member rather than a nested type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general for some type, `T`, `T?` is syntactic sugar for `Optional<T>`.

`Optional<T>` is defined as an `enum` with special compiler support for comparisons and assignments to `nil`.  It looks something like this.

```swift
enum Optional<Wrapped>
{
    case none
    case some(wrapped: Wrapped)
}
```

So when an optional is `nil`, it's actually `.none`

In comments you asked:

> Does the Project.Id bit mean selectedProjectID will be of explicit type the same as the Project.ID member in the struct ?

The answer is no.  `selectedProjectID` is an instance property (a variable) whose type is `Optional<Project.ID>`.  `Project.ID` is a type.  It does also have a type, a meta-type (the type of a type), but I don't think that's what you mean to ask.   I think you're asking if `selectedProjectID` is same type as the `id` property that is defined in `Project` as part of its conformance to `Identifiable`.   And the answer is no, not exactly.

If `someProject` is an instance of `Project`, then `someProject.id` is of type `Project.ID`, whereas `selectedProjectID` is of type `Optional<Project.ID>`.

There is a lot of compiler support extracting, comparing and assigning between optionals and their wrapped type, but strictly speaking they are different types, just as much as `Int` and `Array<Int>` are different types.

On the other hand, assuming `someProjectID` is not `nil`, then `someProjectID!` (ie, force-unwrapped) is the same type as `someProject.id`.  Similarly in

```swift
if let pID = someProjectID {
    ...
}
```

within the `if`, `pID` is also the same type as `someProject.id`